# binding click to dynamic <li> tags using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating dynamic `<li>` tags and, when I click on the `<li>` tag, I want to show an alert with the index of that element. But in the alert only "item 6" is displayed despite of any `<li>` tag being clicked.

My code is:

```
<ul id="list"></ul>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var list = document.getElementById("list");

    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
      var item = document.createElement("li");
      item.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Item " + i));
      item.onclick = function (ev) {
        alert("Item " + i + " is clicked.");
      };
      list.appendChild(item);
    }
</script>
```

When I click on any `<li>` tag, "`item6 is clicked`" always appears in the alert.

I know this problem can be solved using closures but I am not able to implement them.

Comment: Read about `closure in JavaScript`

Comment: i read about closures but i am not able to implement the solution. And if the question is duplicate, can you please tell me where does the same question exist so that i can look for the soluton.  Thanks

Comment: It would be something like this.
                function AppendLi(i,list)
                {
                  var item = document.createElement("li");
                  item.appendChild(document.createTextNode("Item " + i));
                  item.onclick = function (ev) {
                    alert("Item " + i + " is clicked.");
                  };
                  list.appendChild(item);
                }
                var list = document.getElementById("list");
                for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
                  AppendLi(i,list);
                }
            </script>

Comment: Paste the code in an editor to make it readable :)